# Error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error in the sign up/login page of my react app when I click on the submit button. I'm really struggling to figure out the source of this error.

```
export const signUp = formValues => async dispatch => {
    log.info(`[ACTION]: signUp API = ${JSON.stringify(formValues)}.`)

    const response = await authServiceAPI.post('/signup', {
        'username': formValues.username,
        'password': formValues.password,
        'firstname': formValues.firstName,
        'lastname': formValues.lastName,
        'email': formValues.email.toLowerCase(),
    }).catch(err => {
        log.info(`[ACTION]: signUp dispatch HANDLE_SIGN_UP_ERROR err.message=${err.message}.`)
        dispatch({type: HANDLE_SIGN_UP_ERROR, payload: err.message});
    });

    if (response) {
        if (response.data.account_creation_status === 'success') {
            log.info(`[ACTION]: dispatch HANDLE_SIGN_UP account_creation_status = 
            ${response.data.account_creation_status}.`)                                                                 
            history.push("/signin");
        } else {
            console.log('response.data.error_msg = ' + response.data.error_msg);
            log.info(`[ACTION]: dispatch HANDLE_SIGN_UP_ERROR response.data.error_msg = 
            ${response.data.error_msg}.`)
            dispatch({type: HANDLE_SIGN_UP_ERROR, payload: response.data.error_msg});
        }
    }
}
```

This is my actions/index.js file. The message in the catch block gets printed in the console.

```
export const authServiceAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: REACT_APP_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_URL || 
             `http://localhost:${REACT_APP_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_PORT}`
})
```

There is nothing wrong with the url too. Another thing confusing me is that my local node modules folder is empty. I'm using nvm for the project and the .nvm folder doesn't contain the packages which I'm using. This is my docker file:

```
# Base Package
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY ./client/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

#RUN yarn install

# Initiate npm start
CMD [ "npm", "run-script", "start_docker_dev" ]
```

Comment: debug it....
`console.log({
    baseURL: REACT_APP_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_URL || 
             \`http://localhost:${REACT_APP_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_PORT}\`
});`

Comment: @epascarello Will try. Can you pls tell me something about why my node modules folder is empty?

Comment: Did you do npm install? or yarn install? Or whichever package manager you use?

Comment: @entio I'm running the app using docker. I've attached my dockerfile in the question.